# Realizar un recorrido de una columna e insertar un numero N de filas al encontrar un valor

Tags: excel, vba

Ejemplo de insertar filas al encontrar un valor , en la imagen se resalta un ejemplo al encontrar.

Al encontrar una celda con un valor especifico se inserte un numero N de filas arriba de la celda que contiene el valor, lo estaba realizando de la siguiente manera pero no me inserta

```
Sub CargaMigra()

Dim fila As Integer

    fila = 1

    Do While Cells(fila, 1) = ""


        If Cells(fila, 5) = "4.000.000.0000" Then


            Rows.EntireRow.Insert


        End If

        fila = fila + 1

    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Cuando dices "un numero N de filas" ¿de dónde sacas N? Cómo indicas cuantas filas quieres insertar?

Comment: Por cierto, ojo con poner el valor entre comillas. Ahí lo que buscará es una cadena de texto igual a "4.000.000.0000" y no un valor numérico por lo que si en tus celdas tienes números en lugar de texto nunca va a encontrar nada.
Ten en cuenta que al insertar una fila por encima de la actual haces que el bucle Do While nunca termine, ya que metes por ejemplo una fila en la 4 (y la que antes era la 4 ahora es la cinco). El bucle pasa a la fila cinco y encuentra de nuevo el valor 4.000.000.0000, con lo que mete otra fila por encima y la que hace unos segundo era tu fila 5 ahora es tu fila 6.

Answer (score 2):

Tu código con mis comentarios:

```
 Sub CargaMigra()
    Dim fila As Integer
    'IMPORTANTE: Los integer (numeros enteros) en VBA solo almacenan numeros
    'en el rango de –32,768 a 32,767, por tanto si tienes filas superiores a
    '32,767 arrojará un error, por lo cual recomiendo usar LONG
    fila = 1
    Do While Cells(fila, 1) = ""
    'La linea dice esto:
    'Has un bucle (loop) mientras (while) la celda de la fila tal y la columna 1
    'no tengan ningún valor dentro, ningún texto, nada!
    'Por tanto, según dices que debe encontrar algún valor, pues no va a correr
    'si encuentra algo.
        If Cells(fila, 5) = "4.000.000.0000" Then
        'Segun tu código no llegaría acá, pero el IF revisar si la fila tiene
        'el siguiente texto "4.000.000.0000", no un numero, sino un texto
        'si quieres el numero 4000000 debes quitar los puntos y las comillas
        'así mismo debes hacer la prueba con el valor de la celda, no con la celda
        'Cells(fila, 5).value = 4000000 o en su defecto Cells(fila, 5).Value = "4.000.000.0000"
            Rows.EntireRow.Insert
            'y aquí insertas solo una celda... nada mas!
        End If
        fila = fila + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

Ahora mi código con mis comentarios:

```
 Sub CargaMigra2()
    Dim fila As Long: fila = 1 'Así defines e inicializas la variable en una sola linea,
                               'con el tipo de variable long que tiene un rango de datos
                               'de –2,147,483,648 a 2,147,486,647. Mucho mejor

    'cuando quieres agregar filas, lo mejor es ir desde la última fila hacia la primera,
    'por tanto, imaginando que tus datos están el la columna C (colo como ejemplo)

    fila = Range(Cells(1048576, 3), Cells(1048576, 3)).End(xlUp).Row 'aquí se cual es la última linea

    Dim i
    Dim j
    Dim valorBuscado 'as Strig | as integer | as long | as boolean lo que nececites, y si no pones nada,
                     'es tipo Variant, es decir se asigna el tipo de dato según el dato que se guarde
                     'en la variable
    valorBuscado = 1
    Dim cantidadDeFilas As Integer: cantidadDeFilas = 10 'no se de donde asignas este valor
                                                         'o si siempre será el mismo, pero debes
                                                         'de definirlo en algún momento de alguna manera,
                                                         'pero tu ejemplo no define eso, acá puse 10 solo
                                                         'para hacer el ejemplo claro

    For i = fila To 1 Step -1 'imaginando que la hay que revisar hasta la fila uno, por eso ponemos el 1
                              'y Step -1 es para que el loop cuente hacia atras.
        If Cells(i, 3).Value = valorBuscado Then
            For j = 1 To cantidadDeFilas
                  Range(Cells(i, 3), Cells(i, 3)).EntireRow.Insert
                Next j
                'el loop anterior se repite de 1 a la cantidadDeFilas por tanto las filas se van a añadir
                'esa cantidad de veces sobre la fila en cuestión.
            End If
        Next i
    End Sub
```

Espero haber sido suficientemente claro.

Comment: Un par de apuntes a tu respuesta, el `Integer` es un `Long`truncado, nunca utilices integer pues puede dar errores al superar un número mayor a 32000 y algo. En cuanto a insertar filas deberías utilizar sin el bucle de la j: `Range(Cells(i, 1).Resize(CantidadDeFilas).EntireRow.Insert` te ahorras bucles innecesarios. Por último, deberías siempre hacer referencias a libros y hojas previo a los rangos.

Comment: En cuanto al `EntireRow.Insert` tienes toda la razón, creo que es mejor usar el numero de filas pero no como lo pones allí sino de otra forma, porque si estoy en la fila 2 y quiero agrega 20 filas mas, entonces daría error la linea de código que agregar. No soy amante de los loops, pero si son eficientes cuando se pueden acuñar.Y en cuanto al `Integer`, tienes razón, ese punto, (en detalle) lo había anotado al inicio.